# Сравнение файлов построчно

Tags: python, python-2.x, сравнение

Есть код для сравнения файлов и поиска совпадений строк

```
fin = open("c:/SPISOK.txt", "r")
buf = fin.readlines()

for line in buf:
    line2 = line.rstrip('\n')
    with open('c:/FILE.txt', 'r') as file1:
     with open(line2, 'r') as file2:
      same = set(file1).intersection(file2)
      same.discard('\n')
      print line2
     for line in same:
      print line
```

FILE.txt - основной файл для сравнения
SPISOK.txt -список файлов для сравнения

Как брать только 1000 строк для сравнения, из каждого файла списка файлов SPISOK.txt.

SPISOK.txt:

```
c:/1.txt
c:/2.txt
c:/3.txt
```

Строки  FILE.txt трогать не нужно, а нужно все строки  FILE.txt сравнить с каждым  файлом (поочередно) из списка но брать только первые 1000 строк у этих файлов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.islice(it, n)` обрезает любой итератор до длины `n`:

```
from itertools import islice

n = 1000

fin = open("c:/SPISOK.txt", "r")
buf = fin.readlines()

for line in buf:
    line2 = line.rstrip('\n')
    with open('c:/FILE.txt', 'r') as file1:
     with open(line2, 'r') as file2:
      same = set(file1).intersection(islice(file2, n))
      same.discard('\n')
      print line2
     for line in same:
      print line
```

Предыдущий вариант был максимально подогнан под исходный. Можно читать первый файл один раз. Должно быть быстрее и аккуратнее:

```
from itertools import islice

n = 1000

with open('c:/FILE.txt') as file1:
    file1_set = set(file1)
    file1_set.discard('\n')

for fname2 in open('c:/SPISOK.txt'):
    fname2 = fname2.rstrip('\n')
    with open(fname2) as file2:
        print fname2
        for line in file1_set.intersection(islice(file2, n)):
            print line
```

Comment: Спасибо работает!!!

Comment: Но вы всё равно подпилите ещё. `set(file1)` не нужно вычислять всякий раз заново. Один раз в начале только.

Comment: Как это подпилите?

Comment: Спасибо реально шустрее второй вариант

Answer (score 0):

> Как брать только 1000 строк для сравнения, каждого файла из списка файлов SPISOK.txt

если файлы не терабайтные, то лучше выкачать оба файла в 2 буфера, оставить в одном файле только 1000 строк и работать

если файлы огромные - то файл в котором нужно 1000 строк для сравнения выкачать в список, а с другим файлом уже работать напрямую

Comment: В списке файлов много обрезать их не вариант. Файлы большие на десяток миллионов строк. 1000 строк это я для примера написал

Answer (score 0):

Не проверял, пишите, если обнаружите ошибки - поправлю

```
count = 1000 # сколько строк считывать
files_to_check = open('C:\\SPISOK.txt', 'r').readlines() # список файло
main_file = set(open('C:\\FILE.txt', 'r').readlines(count+1)) # читаем "главный" файл

for line in files_to_check: 
    file_name = line.rstip('\n')
    same = main_file.intersection(open(file_name, 'r').readlines(count+1)) # совпадения
    same.discard('\n')
    print(file_name)
    print(*same)
```

Comment: Нет не работает мне строки  FILE.txt трогать не нужно, а нужно все строки  FILE.txt сравнить с каждым  файлом  из списка но брать только первые 1000 строк у этих файлов

Comment: @Виктор вы имеете ввиду, что из FILE.txt нужно все строки считать ?

Comment: Да. Решение получено